# How does ASP.NET MVC know how to fill your model to feed your Controller's Action? Does it involve reflection?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Having defined a `Model`

```
public class HomeModel {
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Surname")]
    public string Surname { get; set; }
}
```

and having the following `Controller`

```
public class HomeController : Controller {
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(HomeModel model) {
        return View(model);
    }

    public ActionResult Index() {

        return View();
    }
}
```

by some "magic" mechanism `HomeModel model` gets filled up with values by ASP.NET MVC. Does anyone know how?

From some rudimentary tests, it seems it will look at the POST response and try to match the response objects name with your Model's properties. But to do that I guess it must use reflection? Isn't that inheritably slow?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you are talking about the magic `ModelBinder`.

`ModelBinder` is responsible for creating a Model and hydrating it with values from the form post-back and performing validation which its result will appear in `ModelState`.

Default implementation is [DefaultModelBinder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.defaultmodelbinder.aspx) but you can plug-in your own.

Answer (score 3):

The DefaultModelBinder indeed uses reflection to set the properties of the model. To be more specific it uses the [SetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.propertydescriptor.setvalue.aspx) method of the PropertyDescriptor class. Of course you can always create a [custom model binder](http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2008/09/08/CustomModelBinderMoreUIValidationASPNETMVC.aspx) to avoid reflection.